# Compact latex document given the current formatting?

Tags: formatting, fontsize

I am trying to compile a latex document that is compact as possible because I am allowed to bring a one paged sheet into an exam I am writing (may sound kind of funny but I think it may be applicable in many cases) and so I really want to make my document as compact as possible. I don't really care if its microscopic font as long as I can read it really close. Currently I thought of the following,

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=0in,top=0in,bottom=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{5}
Some theorem will go here. some math equation $\text{taylor series = } \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{f^(k)(x)(x-a)^{k}}{k!}$ and some more theorems. But I think the general idea is conveyed that I want this to be compact as possible. 

\end{document}
```

Does anyone have any more suggestions for this ? I would greatly appreciate it if I could make it even more compact as I am trying to fit a lot of stuff on that 1 page.

This is what I currently have: [image]

Thanks

Comment: 1) `\documentclass{article}` 2) `\usepackage{amsmath}` 3) `\begin{document}
\fontsize{5}{6}\selectfont` or some thing  4)  `multicol` or `paracol` package may be useful

Comment: I made a change following your advice, but do you know how is it that my equation text is at that small font ? Is it possible to make that font universal for the entire document as opposed to using `$\text{ }$` ?

Comment: I will see but it's `\begin{document} \fontsize{5}{6}\selectfont`

Comment: Ah I see it now, wow that made a huge difference !

Comment: Just use `\tiny`

Comment: Don't use `0pt` margins unless you are sure your printer can print to the edge of the page. Most can't.

Comment: If you use `landscape` with multiple columns, it tends to end up fitting more stuff. Try looking at the formats used for 'cheat sheets` for LaTeX/BibTeX/Biblatex etc. I hope you are allowed a magnifying glass if you're starting with 5pt font and then typesetting subscripts and superscripts!

Comment: @cfr thanks for the advice and good idea. Ill have to get one of those magnification rulers but I'm assuming that typing with a 5 pt font and then using 2x magnification will bring the font size and to 10 right ?

Comment: The subscripts and superscripts will be smaller, though. 2x5pt is not equal to 10pt, but for legibility that should be easier, even if it isn't aesthetically good from a typographical point of view ;).

Comment: Actually, I just printed and its not that small. Maybe I just write everything using superscript fontsize unless that is already the 5pt font.. There isnt anyway of making the fontsize even smaller right ?

Comment: You could simply generate multiple normal font size pages with small margins.  Then print multiple PDF pages to a single physical page using your PDF viewer print settings.

Answer (score 1):

The `savetrees` package saves some additional space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\usepackage[margin=0in,top=0in,bottom=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{savetrees}


\begin{document}
\fontsize{5pt}{5pt}\selectfont
Some theorem will go here. some math equation $\text{taylor series = } \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{f^(k)(x)(x-a)^{k}}{k!}$ and some more theorems. But I think the general idea is conveyed that I want this to be compact as possible. 

\end{document}
```

With `savetrees`:
[image]

Without:
[image]

Comment: as follow from your answer, it is technically possible, but I wonder if this has any useful value? for reading such a tiny text the magnifying glass is needed ... :-)

Comment: @Zarko I am wondering the same, but apparently yes, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301135/compact-latex-document-given-the-current-formatting/426556?noredirect=1#comment729614_301135