# Optimizing a document to contain the least amount of white space/most amount of text

Tags: document-classes

I am currently composing a cheat sheet for an exam using latex base. A lot of space on the page is wasted.

Can anyone give me some tips about how to reduce the amount of white space?

I suspect that the main culprit is `\documentclass[8pt]{article}` in the preamble, maybe there is a better document class for writing chunky documents?

Edit: In case it isn't clear, a lot of space appears to be wasted on the vertical and horizontal margins. The document does however need to allow enough space such that it is printable.

Edit 2: here is the current code. Please ignore the foreign language contents.

```
\documentclass[8pt]{article} \usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage{hyperref} \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\title{Zettel zur Mathe 2} \author{Oscar}

\begin{document} \maketitle

\\ \textbf{Zettel zur Mathe 2} \\ Eulersche Phi-Funktion:  \\ Quotientenregel: $f(x) = \frac{g(x)}{}h(x), f'(x) = \frac{g'(x)h(x) - g(x)h'(x)}{h(x)^2}$ \\ Kettenregel: $f'(x) = u'(v(x)) \cdot v'(x)$ \\ Produktenregel: $(f(x) \cdot g(x))' = f'(x) \cdot g(x) + f(X) \cdot g'(x)$ \\ L'Hôpital: $\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to c} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ if $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) \vee g(x) = 0 \vee \plusminus \infty$ \\ Differentialquotient: $f'(x_0) = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h}$ \\ Bogenlaenge: $\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{1 + (f'(x))^2} dx$ \\ Partielle Integration: $\int^b_a u(x) v'(x) dx = [u(x)v(x)]^b_a - \int^b_a u'(x) v(x) dx$ \\ Taylor: $T(x) = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty {\frac{{{f^{\left( n \right)}}\left( a \right)}}{{n!}}{{\left( {x - a} \right)}^n}} = f(a)
+ f'(a)(x-a) + \frac{f''(a)}{2!} \cdot (x-a)^2 + \dots$ \\ \textbf{Integrals:} \\ $ \int \sin{(x)} dx = -\cos{(x)} + C, \int \cos{(x)} dx = \sin{(x)} + C, \int \sec^2{(x)} dx = \tan{(x)} + C$  \\ $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} = \sin^{-1}(x) + C = \arcsin(x) + C$ \\ $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} = -\cos^{-1}(x) + C = \arccos(x) + C$ \\ $\int \frac{1}{x^2 + 1} dx= \tan^{-1}(x) + C = \arctan(x) + C $ \\ Complex Integrals: $\tan(x), \ln(x)$ \\ $\int e^x dx = e^x + C, \int \frac{1}{x} = \ln{(|x|)} + C$



\end{document}
```

Comment: There are lots of ways of cutting down whitespace.  And, LaTeX can definitely be used for creating a tight cheat sheet.  Give MWE of what you've put together so we can show you how to cut down the whitespace.

Comment: `savetrees` package :)

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301135/compact-latex-document-given-the-current-formatting/426556#426556

Comment: @A.Ellett sorry, I am unfamiliar with the acronym MWE. I have pasted a block of code, I hope this is helpful/acceptable?

Comment: Using \\ for line breaks is not a good idea, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66495/best-choice-between-using-or-leaving-space-after-each-paragraph-to-end-the-pa

Comment: @samcarter sorry for the poor formatting. I am very much still in the process of learning.

Comment: note `article` doesn't have an `8pt` option (you get a warning about that) and the first `\\ ` produces an error (after an error it is best not to look at the pdf output which usually isn't sensible)

Comment: Maybe this help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/72785/11604

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that shows how tightly things can be crammed without using too many bells and whistles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=0.25cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{4}
\footnotesize
\lipsum[1-19]
\end{document}
```

One thing to notice is how I've used the `multicol` package.

But, when it comes to cheatsheets, I would not just work it as any other document.  I would take another approach of using `minipage`s to compartmentalize  the various details I want to keep on the sheet.

So, I would in addition to using `multicol` as in the above example, I would define an environment for each type of note you want to make: let's call it `note`.  And then I'll define a command `\notetitle`.  So each cheatsheet note would be of the form

```
\begin{note}
  \notetitle{Definite Integral}
  Everything I want to remember about definite integrals
  will be entered here.
\end{note}
```

which will create something like

[image]

So that gives you the basic idea.  Here's how I'll define that environment:

```
\newsavebox\aebox
\newenvironment{note}
  {\begin{lrbox}\aebox
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth/5
                                -\columnsep
                                -2\fboxrule
                                -2\fboxsep}
      \setlength\parskip{0pt}%%
      \setlength\parindent{0pt}%% make everything very tight
      \small\raggedright
  }{%%
  \end{minipage}%%
  \end{lrbox}%%
  \noindent\fbox{\usebox{\aebox}}\newline}
\newcommand\notetitle[1]{\par\textbf{#1:}\newline}
```

There's no particular reason to frame the box, but I find that if I don't, then it'll be hard to find things.  Your call.  If you don't want to frame things, then remove the call to `\fbox` and remove `-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep` to save more space.

Since I'm going to use five columns across the page, I will divide the total `\textwidth` by `5`.  I need to take into consideration the space between the columns, hence `-\columnsep`.

You can then cram a lot into one page:

[image]

Obviously, I'm just repeating one of your notes.  But, I wanted to populate the entire page so you can see how much information can potential fit on to a page.

Here's the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=0.125in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\columnsep{1pt}
\setlength\fboxsep{2pt}
\newsavebox\aebox
\newenvironment{note}
  {\begin{lrbox}\aebox
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth/5
                                -1\columnsep
                                -2\fboxrule
                                -2\fboxsep}
      \setlength\parskip{0pt}%%
      \setlength\parindent{0pt}%% make everything very tight
      \small\raggedright
  }{%%
  \end{minipage}%%
  \end{lrbox}%%
  \noindent\fbox{\usebox{\aebox}}\newline}
\newcommand\notetitle[1]{\par\textbf{#1:}\newline}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{5}

\begin{note}
  \notetitle{Quotientenregel $f(x) = \frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$}
  \footnotesize
  $f'(x) = \frac{g'(x)h(x) -
  g(x)h'(x)}{h(x)^2}$
\end{note}
\begin{note}
  \notetitle{Kettenregel:}
    $f'(x) = u'(v(x)) \cdot v'(x)$ \\ 
\end{note}
\begin{note}
  \notetitle{Produktenregel:} $(f(x) \cdot g(x))' = f'(x)
\cdot g(x) + f(X) \cdot g'(x)$ \\ 
\end{note}
\begin{note}
  \notetitle{L'Hôpital} 
    $\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 
     \lim_{x \to c} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ 
  if $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) \vee g(x) = 0 \vee \pm \infty$
  \notetitle{Differentialquotient} 
    $f'(x_0) = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h}$ 
  \notetitle{Bogenlaenge} 
    $\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{1 + (f'(x))^2} dx$ 
  \notetitle{Partielle Integration} 
    $\int^b_a u(x) v'(x) dx = [u(x)v(x)]^b_a - \int^b_a u'(x) v(x) dx$ 
  \notetitle{Taylor} 
    $T(x) = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty {\frac{{{f^{\left( n \right)}}\left( a \right)}}{{n!}}{{\left( {x - a} \right)}^n}} 
          = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + \frac{f''(a)}{2!} \cdot (x-a)^2 + \dots$ 
\end{note}
\begin{note}
  \textbf{Integrals:} \\ $ \int \sin{(x)} dx = -\cos{(x)} + C, \int \cos{(x)} dx = \sin{(x)} + C, \int \sec^2{(x)} dx = \tan{(x)} + C$  \\ $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} = \sin^{-1}(x) + C = \arcsin(x) + C$ \\ $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} = -\cos^{-1}(x) + C = \arccos(x) + C$ \\ $\int \frac{1}{x^2 + 1} dx= \tan^{-1}(x) + C = \arctan(x) + C $ \\ Complex Integrals: $\tan(x), \ln(x)$ \\ $\int e^x dx = e^x + C, \int \frac{1}{x} = \ln{(|x|)} + C$
\end{note}
%%
.... no need to show all the repeated notes ....    
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

There's no reason to bother with nuisances like `\title`, `\author`, `\maketitle`.  This isn't an actual article.  Why waste space with such nonsense (unless you're publishing and it's not nonsense).

Avoid any formatting that likes to embellish things with whitespace.  Don't use `\\` unless you're presenting a table of values.  Avoid using `\newline` except where absolutely necessary.  I've whittled down the paragraph formatting by setting both `\parskip` and `\parindent` to `0pt`.  That'll save more space.